# filename with characters from U+0400 to U+041F don't open attachments in Internet Explorer 9 and 10

Tags: java, internet-explorer, filenames, stripes

I have a problem with this cyrillic characters in the filename of an attachment, , only the range from U+0400 to U+041F, do fail to open the files from my java web applicattion. Our encoding is UTF-8 and fails only in IE, in firefox, chrome, etc works perfect. The filename should be unchanged, any ideas why this is happening,

Examples where we have the problem

Worksheet in MDM - З.xls

Worksheet in MDM - Ж.xls

The code to open the files is:

```
    String filename = at.getFtpFileName();
    filename = new String(filename.getBytes(), "UTF-8");

    AttachmentHandler handler = AttachmentHandlerFactory.getAttachementHandler(protocol);

    StreamingResolution streamingResolution = new StreamingResolution(getMimeType(filename),
            handler.getInputStream(filename)).setFilename(filename);

    streamingResolution.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return streamingResolution;
```

Thank you

Comment: What code are you using for sending the file?

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: The problematic characters are some capital letters in cyrillic. I've found the problem was in a bug of the framework stripes we're using, it didn't recognize some characters in the filename. the bug is solved in the new version of stripes 1.5.

Comment: I meant the code you're using to send the file to the client...

Comment: Hi, the code I copied it in the first description is java, with this code you send back the data to the client. Don't worry the problem was on the framework, thanks

Comment: At which point I can only bow out, as my knowledge of stripes is non existant - it's useful when raising questions to tag them with at least the language or framework that you're writing your code in.